# Persisting in joined tables with JPA and JSF

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jakarta-ee, jpa

My model contains the classes **Student** and **Course** (see below).

**Student.java**:

```
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "SelectStudents", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s"), })
@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8776005542073703016L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Size(min = 3, max = 30)
    private String firstName;

    @Size(min = 3, max = 30)
    private String lastName;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Past
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    private String email;

    @Size(min = 5, max = 5)
    private String regNr;

    private String faculty;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "StudentCourse", joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private List<Course> courses;

    public Student() {
    }

    // getter and setter
}
```

**Course.java**:

```
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "SelectCourses", query = "SELECT c FROM Course c"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "SelectStudentCoursesByName", query = "SELECT c FROM Course c WHERE c.name = :name") })
@Entity
public class Course implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5955154651849644853L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private int cp;

    public Course() {
    }
    // getter and setter
}
```

The controllers look like the following.

**StudentController.java**:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "studentController")
@SessionScoped
public class StudentController {

    private DataModel<Student> students;

    private Student student = new Student();

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction utx;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        students = new ListDataModel<Student>();
        students.setWrappedData(em.createNamedQuery("SelectStudents")
                .getResultList());
    }

    public String newStudent() {
        this.student = new Student();
        return "newStudent?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public String saveStudent() {
        try {
            utx.begin();
        } catch (NotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        student = em.merge(student);
        em.persist(student);
        students.setWrappedData(em.createNamedQuery("SelectStudents")
                .getResultList());
        try {
            utx.commit();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RollbackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (HeuristicMixedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (HeuristicRollbackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "studentList";
    }

    public String deleteStudent() {
        try {
            utx.begin();
        } catch (NotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        student = students.getRowData();
        // Transaktionsbeginn
        student = em.merge(student);
        em.remove(student);
        students.setWrappedData(em.createNamedQuery("SelectStudents")
                .getResultList());
        try {
            utx.commit();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RollbackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (HeuristicMixedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (HeuristicRollbackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "studentList?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public String editStudent() {
        student = students.getRowData();
        return "newStudent";
    }
    // getter and setter
}
```

**CourseController.java**:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class CourseController {

    private DataModel<Course> courses;

    private Course course;

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction utx;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        courses = new ListDataModel<Course>();
        courses.setWrappedData(em.createNamedQuery("SelectCourses")
                .getResultList());
    }

    public String newCourse() {
        this.course = new Course();
        return "newCourse?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public String saveCourse() {
        try {
            utx.begin();
        } catch (NotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        course = em.merge(course);
        em.persist(course);
        courses.setWrappedData(em.createNamedQuery("SelectCourses")
                .getResultList());
        try {
            utx.commit();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RollbackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (HeuristicMixedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (HeuristicRollbackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "courseList?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public String deleteCourse() {
        try {
            utx.begin();
        } catch (NotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        course = courses.getRowData();
        // Transaktionsbeginn
        course = em.merge(course);
        em.remove(course);
        courses.setWrappedData(em.createNamedQuery("SelectCourses")
                .getResultList());
        try {
            utx.commit();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RollbackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (HeuristicMixedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (HeuristicRollbackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "courseList?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public String editCourse() {
        course = courses.getRowData();
        return "newCourse?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    // getter and setter
}
```

I have created JSF pages and I am able to add, delete and edit **Students** and **Courses** in my Java EE application.

As you can see the join table **StudentCourse** is created automatically by JPA. I now want to be able to add already created and persisted **Courses** to already created and persisted **Students**, so that **Students** can be registered in any number of **Courses**. The reference would be stored in the **StudentCourse** table, in my MySQL database.

Is it a good idea to create a join table or should I create a model class **StudentCourse** and a controller **StudentCourseController** to implement the problem?

Comment: Please consider migrating the business logic to its own place where container managed transactions are available and consequently, you will not have to play with bean managed transactions manually. Do you severely dislike that place? :)

Comment: Never thought about it. But in my project it is a specification to use Managed Beans.

Comment: Please ask one question per Question.

Answer (score 1):

For what your question describes a join table is enough however if you later want to add attributes like the grade they got then you will need an extra entity class to model the relation.

Comment: The course does have credit points, do you mean that? It is not just a name. Another question is, how to persist a course for a student and how to access it via JSF? I don't have that much experience yet. :(